# Unreal Engine 4.24.3: No instance of constructor Error when declaring TArray<FString> in a header file

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, unreal-engine4, declare

I've been trying to create a header file that will declare a TArray of FStrings but keep getting the following compiler error:

"C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list            argument types are: (const wchar_t [6], const wchar_t [6], const wchar_t [6], const wchar_t [6], const wchar_t [6])"

I have read the documentation from Unreal here on declaring and initializing a TArray to no avail: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/TArrays/index.html

```
const TArray<FString> WordList;
WordList.Add("test");
```

When attempting this, the compiler throws an error stating that there is no storage class or type specifier.

What is the correct way of declaring a TArray within a header file in Unreal?

```
 #include "CoreMinimal.h"


const TArray<FString> WordList = { 
TEXT("chart"),
TEXT("quest"),
TEXT("crows"),
TEXT("bears"),
TEXT("loves") };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ok, and it compiles in my VStudio, I am not sure about that error, but to be exact the error says that you created a TArray of "FString" items and you are adding TEXT("abcd") which is of type "wchar_t*".
Try this one:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
const TArray<wchar_t*> WordList = { 
TEXT("chart"),
TEXT("quest"),
TEXT("crows"),
TEXT("bears"),
TEXT("loves") };
```

or

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
const TArray<FString> WordList = { 
"chart",
"quest",
"crows",
"bears",
"loves" };
```

The below code will work only in .cpp file and you should drop `const` to work with `Add`:

```
TArray<FString> WordList;
WordList.Add("test");
```